# VS 2010 template with package restore enabled

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, nuget

I want to create a project template that will have "Enable NuGet package restore" already enabled. But if I export a template with this option ticked, then when I try to create a new project (the first project in a new solution) based on this template I get the message that "..\Solution.nuget\nuget.targets" does not exist. Is it possible to install the necessary files automatically?

I can add the project to an existing solution, if the option is enabled.

Comment: Did you try 'Multi-Project Templates'? And add there .nuget folder with related files. About Multi-Project Templates: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms185308(v=vs.10)

Comment: @PavelBakshy - I can't see how I can select multiple projects, there is dropdown so only one is selectable at a time, even though point 6 suggests otherwise: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/xkh1wxd8(v=vs.100)
I think I should be able to edit .vstemplate file manually and then add required files to folder, but that seems like a lot of work.

Comment: Both links above contain the closing bracket in the text, but not in the link. Put the ) inside the pasted LINK and the links will work.